# Android Studio count not outputting number correctly

Tags: android, counter

I made a code to show the amount of times a vowel is used. A, E, I, O, U. The code is counting but it is not conunting correctly.

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int letter1 = 0;
                int letter2 = 0;
                String enter1 = str1.getText().toString();
                String enter2 = str2.getText().toString();

                for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
                    if (enter1.charAt(i) == 'a' || enter1.charAt(i) == 'e' || enter1.charAt(i) == 'i' || enter1.charAt(i) == 'o' ||
                            enter1.charAt(i) == 'u')
                    {
                        letter1++;
                    }

                 for(int j = 0; j < str2.length(); j ++){
                     if(enter2.charAt(j) == 'a' || enter2.charAt(j) == 'e' || enter2.charAt(j) == 'i' || enter2.charAt(j) == 'o' ||
                             enter2.charAt(j) == 'u')
                     {
                         letter2++;
                     }
                 }

                  display3.setText("The amount of vowels are :"+ letter1 + " & " +  letter2);
                }

            }
        });
```

My output for Hello World is 2 and 5. 2 for Hello is correct but 5 for World is not. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to check your brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we reformat the code slightly, the problem is more apparent:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
     if (enter1.charAt(i) == 'a' || enter1.charAt(i) == 'e' || enter1.charAt(i) == 'i' || enter1.charAt(i) == 'o' ||
         enter1.charAt(i) == 'u') {
         letter1++;
     }

     for (int j = 0; j < str2.length(); j++) {
         if (enter2.charAt(j) == 'a' || enter2.charAt(j) == 'e' || enter2.charAt(j) == 'i' || enter2.charAt(j) == 'o' ||
             enter2.charAt(j) == 'u') {
             letter2++;
         }
     }

     display3.setText("The amount of vowels are :" + letter1 + " & " + letter2);
 }
```

As you can see, the second `for` loop is inside the first one. That means the second number will be N times larger than it should be, where N is the length of the first word. This matches what's happening: there is only 1 vowel in "world" but there are 5 letters in "hello".

The `display3.setText(...)` part will also be executed N times, but since it overwrites the previous value you won't be able to notice that, and you'll just see the final value.

To fix, just close the first `for` loop earlier:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
     if (enter1.charAt(i) == 'a' || enter1.charAt(i) == 'e' || enter1.charAt(i) == 'i' || enter1.charAt(i) == 'o' ||
         enter1.charAt(i) == 'u') {
         letter1++;
     }
 }

 for (int j = 0; j < str2.length(); j++) {
     if (enter2.charAt(j) == 'a' || enter2.charAt(j) == 'e' || enter2.charAt(j) == 'i' || enter2.charAt(j) == 'o' ||
         enter2.charAt(j) == 'u') {
         letter2++;
     }
 }

 display3.setText("The amount of vowels are :" + letter1 + " & " + letter2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something problem with the brackets

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           for(Loop){
                   if(condition){

                    }
            }//first loop

            for(Loop){
                   if(condition){

                    }
            }//second loop


           //display here              

        });//end for onClick
```